# Ajax, using div tags to set javascript values

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, tags

I can easily set div tags using ajax. However i want to set javascript values using ajax. I had tried reading the div tags using `javaScriptVariable = div.innerHTML` but it comes out blank.

Can anyone please help? thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Log In</title>

<!-- script tag for ajax jquery -->
<link href='style.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()

              {
              //Get Data ajax function 
              $.post(
                     'getData.php',
                     {

                     },                                           
                     function(response)
                     {
                     $('#name').html($('#1' , response).html());
                     $('#sname').html($('#2' , response).html());                                           
                     })
              return false;
              })

var x;
x = name.innerHTML;
document.write(x);

</script>

</head>

<body>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have elements called `#name` and `#sname` either. Keep in mind that Ajax is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't pass a value to jquery's html() method, it will return the current value:

```
var x = $('#name').html();
document.write(x);
```

Comment: This covers up the other HTML elements. It works but every other HMTL element is covered up. Can you help stop this?

Comment: In your example, you're using document.write in the head tag...which could cause all kinds of problems.  If it's in your body, though, then it's a CSS issue, not a JS issue.

Answer (score 1):

That is because these two lines execute as soon as the script loads.  I am assuming that that element is probably empty at this time.

```
x = name.innerHTML;
document.write(x);
```

You will need to set `x` when the ajax call comes back.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Get Data ajax function 
    $.post(
        'getData.php',
        {

        },                                           
        function(response)
        {
            $('#name').html($('#1' , response).html());
            $('#sname').html($('#2' , response).html());

            var x = $('#name').html();
            document.write(x);
        })
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! I have spent a day on this haha

Comment: This covers up the other HTML elements. It works but every other HMTL element is covered up. Can you help stop this?

Answer (score 1):

You are having a problem because you do not have a variable `name` defined anywhere.

Why bother going through the div anyway? just go to the var directly:

```
var x;
// ...

                 function(response)
                 {
                 $('#name').html($('#1' , response).html());
                 $('#sname').html($('#2' , response).html());
                 //this will set x, you can do this instead of, or in addition to the above
                 x = $('#1' , response).html();
                 })
```